# Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.FeedBack'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> {"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_FeedBack'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.FeedBack'. The duplicate key value is
>   (0).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

```
public int InsertFeedBack(FeedBack fb)
    {
        db.FeedBacks.Add(fb);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return fb.ID;
    }
```

```
public JsonResult Send(string name, string mobile, string address, string email, string content)
    {
        var feedback = new FeedBack();
        feedback.Name = name;
        feedback.Email = email;
        feedback.CreatDate = DateTime.Now;
        feedback.Phone = mobile;
        feedback.Content = content;
        feedback.Address = address;

        var id = new LHeDAO().InsertFeedBack(feedback);
        if (id > 0)
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                status = true
            });
            //send mail
        }

        else
            return Json(new
            {
                status = false
            });
    }
```

```
public partial class FeedBack
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreatDate { get; set; }

    public bool? status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: the tags look wrong. this is c# not java.  I see no javascript or php or anything that has to do with android.

Answer (score 5):

I think for your ID you need to have

```
 [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

and make sure the ID is set as the identity column in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` to automatically generate the ID or generate ID yourself( Must be unique).

Answer (score 0):

The code example that you have provided doesn't show any initialization of `ID`:

```
    var feedback = new FeedBack();
    feedback.Name = name;
    feedback.Email = email;
    feedback.CreatDate = DateTime.Now;
    feedback.Phone = mobile;
    feedback.Content = content;
    feedback.Address = address;

    var id = new LHeDAO().InsertFeedBack(feedback);**
```

and you explicitly state that the database should not generate it:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int ID { get; set; }
```

so `ID` is getting initialized to 0 by default, and the database is returning that error on attempt to insert because you already have a row in the table where `ID` is 0. To fix this, you either need to allow the database to generate the value for `ID` or initialize `ID` with a unique value before attempting to perform the insert.